# ¿Por qué la salida por consola es 8 en este código?

Tags: c++, enum

Estoy intentado entender porque al declarar la funcion `f` e introducirla en la principal `main` sale 8.

```
#include <iostream>
enum color {blanco, azul, rojo, amarillo=8};
void f(int x) {
if (x == 1)
throw x;
else
std::cout << amarillo << std::endl;
}
int main() {
try {
f(2);
f(1);
std::cout << blanco << "B" << rojo << std::endl;
} catch (int ex) {
std::cout << azul << "A" << rojo << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "C" << blanco << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Sale 8 cuándo? ¿Qué salida esperabas?

Comment: ahi dice que amarillo es 8... porque no saldria 8?

Comment: Mi duda es como sale esa salida en concreto. Las dos últimas las entiendo, pero no esa.

Comment: Cuando haces `f(2)`, entonces, la función `f` ejecuta  `cout<< amarillo ` (porque no se cumple `x==1`)  y como amarillo es igual a 8 entonces se muestra el 8 en la consola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por esta linea de tu codigo, que siempre pinta amarillo:

```
std::cout << amarillo << std::endl;
```

Y por esta otra, donde amarillo vale 8:

```
enum color {blanco, azul, rojo, amarillo=8};
```

entonces, claramente, siempre pinta un 8
:)